# GCP node schedule with zone fallback

Tags: kubernetes, gcloud

I'm using preemptive machines for some node pools from my GKE Cluster, and I often get the following error saying the zone resources have been exausted:

| Error Type | Error Message |
| --- | --- |
| ZONE_RESOURCE_POOL_EXHAUSTED_WITH_DETAILS | Instance 'gke-prod-private-clu-getvalues-preemp-423b7c55-bsnk' creation failed: The zone 'projects/import-sheet/zones/us-central1-a' does not have enough resources available to fulfill the request. '(resource type:compute)'. |

Is it possible to have a node preferably scheduled to zone **us-central1-a** and, in case it doesn't have the resources, fallback to other zones with available resources?

I know you can enable redundancy on multiple zones, but that would be expensive. I want only one replica at whatever zone has resources available.